# Shiny app does not react on action button

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I have what seems to be a perfectly fine R Shiny app, but for some reason it does not react on action button. Minimal reproducible example below.
Nothing happens, no error is thrown. It just does not react. It's like the app is frozen.

```r
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
   actionButton('go_button','Go!'),
   uiOutput('my_output'),
   uiOutput('my_output')
  ),
  server = function(input,output,session) {
    observeEvent(input$go_button,{
      output$my_output = renderUI({HTML('this is my output')})
    })
  }
)
```

Comment: In general, HTML doesn't allow duplicate element ids (stackoverflow.com/questions/22059438/html-duplicated-id). For clarity, you can open developer tools and see the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the second `uiOutput('my_output')` in `ui`. Removing it brings back reactivity.

Note: I am sharing this Q&A-style because it took me one hour to figure it out in my real app. It is way longer and messier than the MRE above, so the fact that I had the same output twice was not obvious (they were on different tabs, moreover). Plus, I did not even know that displaying the same output in more than one place in the app was forbidden.

Finally, the complete silence (no error or warning whatsoever) did not help.

I hope it can save other people in my situation some time!

Comment: will do. I still need to wait one day :)